# SELECT EXISTS in Sybase

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sap-ase

I have the following query in PostgreSQL (`1=1` is a placeholder for some arbitrary condition as apparently I can't write `WHERE TRUE` in Sybase)

```
SELECT EXISTS FROM (
    SELECT 1 FROM someTable WHERE 1=1  
)
```

How do I translate them for SQL Server / Sybase syntax ?
A roundabout way is to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT 1 FROM someTable WHERE 1=1  
) a
```

… which can further be simplified to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM someTable WHERE 1=1
```

… but `EXISTS` is cleaner and I believe it's in the ANSI standard as well.

Comment: What is this query supposed to do?

Comment: In TSQL, that `where 1=1` is doing absolutely nothing.  What are you including it for?

Comment: @TimSchmelter return TRUE or FALSE depending on whether a row exists in table `someTable` that satisfies some arbitrary condition (`1=1` is a placeholder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) doesn't return a value that you can select (I don't know why). You can check `if exists()`, but not `select exists()`. You can also check `where exists()` or even `case when exists()`.

```
select 
    E = case 
        when exists(
          select 1 from master..spt_values
        ) 
          then 1
        else 0 
        end
```

If you are trying to get counts for multiple different criteria, a common pattern for sql server would be something like:

```
select 
    ACount     = sum(case when x='A' then 1 else 0 end)
  , ABCount    = sum(case when x in ('A','B') then 1 else 0 end)
  , TotalCount = count(*) /* or sum(1) */ 
from someTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expect for 'EXISTS' but this might do the trick

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table WHERE 1 = 1)
```

Comment: This returns an empty result set if the condition does not hold. It is not guaranteed to return TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: That's why I asked in my comment that I wasn't sure what exists was supposed to do.  I could edit my anser but the answer below solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE 1=1), 1, 0)
```

Comment: [Code: 156, SQL State: S1000]  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus This query runs from SQL Server 2012 onwards. Which version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that in the comment. I ran it on Sybase ASE 15.7